# Flask - requests beginning with static/ don't match '/<path:path>' unless static_url_path is non-empty

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask

On the server, in `index.py`, I instantiate the `app` like this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```

and there are these routes:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return send_file('build/index.html')

@app.route('/<path:path>')
def send_resource(path):
    print 'I MATCHED THIS ROUTE'
    return send_from_directory('build', path)
```

---

The client is a React app, which when built with `npm run build`, puts this script tag into `build/index.html` to fetch the now bundled js:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/main.4b.js">
```

and it also creates such a file `build/static/js/main.4b.js`.

---

The interesting thing that happens is when I run the server and navigate to `http://localhost:5000/static/js/main.4b.js` in my browser, `'/<path:path>'` is NOT matched, so it doesn't run the function `send_resource`, I don't see the printout, the js file cannot be found and I see a 404 in the server logs:

```
... "GET /static/js/main.4b.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

But when I request a URL that doesn't start with `static/` (like `stati/js/main.4b.js` or `staticness/js/main.4b.js` or `bobby/js/main.4b.js`), it DOES match `'/<path:path>'`, and that function is run so I see the printout (though I correctly still get a 404 because those files don't exist).

---

I can FIX this problem by changing the app instantiation to

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/')
```

and put whatever I want as the `static_url_path` (except `''`), and the route will now get matched on a request to `/static/js/main.4b.js` and the file will be sent to the client, as intended.

But I don't understand why. What is going on with static files and static paths that causes this special behavior for requests to routes that begin with `static/`?

EDIT:
My file structure is

```
project/
  build/
    static/
      js/
        main.4b.js
      ...
    index.html
  index.py
  ...
```

Comment: Could you please also post the file-structure of your project?

Comment: It's a documented feature: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#static-files

Comment: @KlausD. I saw that but don't quite understand it. 1) why would we want to use `url_for` (in a route handler, not a template), 2) can i change it so it looks in `build/static/` instead of `static/`?